# How to post an image in Python just like byte array in Java?

Tags: python, django

On my Django backend, I deal with images like this:

```
for file in request.FILES.iteritems():
            image = request.FILES["image"]
```

It is easy to send a post request via java using a byte array.

But how to do a post request using Python?

As in, I've an image url.

I've downloaded the iamge from an url using

```
r = requests.get('url')
r.content #ImageConent
```

Now how do I post it such that it is delivered as a byte array?

Comment: Post it where? Do you mean a HTTP POST to another server?

Comment: Also, your `for` loop is not necessary. Just execute `image = request.FILES["image"]` *without the loop*.

Comment: I intend to do an HTTP post.

Comment: I basically have an instagram image url, which I plan to download and send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) on how to send multipart requests. Basically you just need to do:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}   
>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Or in your case:

```
>>> r = requests.get(url1)
>>> files = {'image': r.content}   
>>> r = requests.post(url2, files=files)
```

Comment: Except the OP has the image data in memory, not a file. You'd either need to explain how to write it to a file, or how to use something like `StringIO()` to make it file-like. But we have to establish first and foremost what the OP was intending to *do* with the image.

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'image' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>"

Comment: that seems to be a problem on your django part. I've just tested file upload using requests to a simpe django view, and it should work like described.